# How to use audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying in one class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Player1 works well ,but I have an error implementing Player2.

How should I change audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying to make it work?

Here is the code for my ViewController.swift:

```
  func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if (player === player2) {
        yourButton2.isSelected = false
    } else {
　　　　　yourButton.isSelected = false
        player2!.play()
        yourButton2.isSelected = false
    }
}


  func Player1(url: URL) {
    do {
        try player2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
        player2!.play()
        yourButton2.isSelected = true
        player2!.delegate = self

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

  func Player2(url: URL, url2: URL) {
    do {
        try player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
        try player2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url2)
        player1!.play()
        yourButton.isSelected = true
        player1!.delegate = self
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `audioPlayerdidFinishPlaying(_:successfully:)` you have a `else if`-clause that will never become `true`:

```
} else if (player === player3) {
```

`player3` will **always** be `nil` because you are never assigning something to it. Thus your 3rd branch in `audioPlayerdidFinishPlaying(_:successfully:)` will never be executed. To make this work within you current class design, you need to either:

- Change the `else if` clause
- Assign something to `player3`

Comment: I have edited else if cause but still it did not work out well. Will you tell me what is the problem ?